# Jetpack Compose: How to connect 2 LazyColumns

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

## What my goal is

I want to connect a `LazyColumn` that has reversed Layout enabled with a 'usual' `LazyColumn`, so that it seems for the user like it was one List and not two.

reversed LazyColumn: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PGuF.gif
usual LazyColumn: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5gB1.gif
(Cannot attach more than 3 links I think)

```
connected: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayfZP.gif][3]
```

## What is the purpose of two lazyColumns

I want to achieve infinite scrolling in both direction with pagination.
If I wanted to achieve infinite pagination in both directions with one `lazyColumn/List` I would have to put elements at the front and also at the end. Putting items at the end isn't a problem but at the front you get this jumping behavior (the lazyColumn always directly jumps to `index 0` of the list).
To avoid this, one lazyColumn that is reversed handles the elements which were previously added at the front (since the layout is reversed, you can add elements at the end of the list as usual), and the second lazyColumn that is **not** reversed handles the elements which were previously added at the end.

## What my approach is

The lazyColumns are collapsible and expandable. That means when the reversed lazyColumn is at `Index 0` and you scroll further it collapses on your scroll, meanwhile the other lazyColumns takes up the free space (expands). So the user shouldn't be aware of this collapsing/expanding process, it seems like the list scrolls fluently.

## What is the problem

I think, this could be done with `NestedScrolling`. But it's a bit hard to think of, because both elements are scrollable. That's why both elements are able to trigger the expanding/collapsing process.
Has someone a tip how I could connect these 2 `lazyColums`?
Thank you for all answers!

Comment: I don't get it. Is what you want trying to make two lazy scrollables scroll together when one of them is scrolled?

Comment: Basically connect the scrollability of the two?

Comment: That can be done by lazyListState. Just get the firstVisibleItemScrollOffset and animateScrollOffset in a coroutine. Add the scrolling to both so that any one can be used to invoke the other.

Comment: @MARSK usually you start from the beginning of a dataset and then scroll down with pagination. - So I‘m starting in the middle of this calendar ‚dataset‘, I‘m starting at the current month. That’s why you can scroll up ⬆️ to scroll to years in the past and you can scroll down ⬇️ to scroll to years in the future. So I had this approach to have a reversed lazycolumn to scroll up to the past years and a lazycolumn to scroll down to the future years. Benefit: You can add elements at the end of the list and haven’t to add items at the front. The only thing is, I have to connect these at index 0.

Comment: @Philip Dukhov had this other approach how to solve this problem with adding elements at the front. I am going to test it today.